# Multiple textures are not importing

Tags: texturing

So Im having a problem with blender find multiple texture images. I downloaded an object that came with textures and imported the object. But the textures came up pink and there are a lot of textures so I am trying to avoid importing each texture . I tried to add the images by using the "find missing files" option but it keeps saying it could not find the files, even though the file names are exactly the same as the textures in blender.

Not sure how to fix this, any help would be great

Thank You